# Wordpress upgraded to 3.4 to 3.5.1 and getting 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress

I upgraded my website from wordpress 3.4 to 3.5.1, and after doing that, i am getting, 500 Internal Server Error. Though my backend of wordpress is running perfect. Only the front end is shwoing this error.

I tried changing permalinks, change my theme to twenty eleven, but no help.

My website is on GoDaddy's Windows server, so i tried with web.congig as well, but still it's same.

Comment: Probably, the theme or some plugin is mis-behaving. Check this [troubleshoot guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list).

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log, probably solutions could be:

- Change permission from 0644 to 0755
- Add this code to your wp-config file:

> require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-embed.php' );

- Clean your .htaccess and change it to:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  ```

Comment: i think u didn't read it thoroughly i mentioned, my website is in WINDOWS server, hope u know, windows server don't have any .htaccess, that is for linux server. And for windows server i,e web.config, i already edited that.